# Conflicting mod_rewrite with authentication

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I am server admin which hosts many sites. One of them is running wordpress. If password protect wp-admin/ through cPanel, when browse to site0.com/wp-admin, it falls into a redirect loop.

I found out that this behavior is because wp-admin redirects to `wp-login.php` if not logged in and if is password protected, somehow authentication rules in `.htaccess` of wp-admin conflicts with rewriterule(s) in global `.htaccess` (in public_html) and so redirection goes infinitely. Then if I comment rewriterule(s), login comes up, however inner pages of WordPress no longer work.

public_html/.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

public_html/wp-admin/.htaccess:

```
AuthUserFile "/home/paraf/.htpasswds/public_html/wp-admin/passwd"
AuthName "wp-admin"

<Files admin-ajax.php>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  Satisfy any 
</Files>

AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

Comment: This is by definition, not exactly the place where you solve your customer's tickets.

Comment: So you think as it my own problem. How does it make difference?

Comment: Why don't you tell us what exactly are you trying to achieve? Protecting wp-admin by htaccess is unnecessary I think, so maybe you are solving problem that isn't there. You can also try accessing wp-login.php directly. Maybe that will do the trick?

Comment: Oh! You're right it is totally stupid to password protect wp-admin as wp-login.php is accessablefrom outside of wp-admin.

Comment: I'll post that as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Protecting wp-admin by htaccess is unnecessary I think, so maybe you are solving problem that isn't there. You can still access wp-login.php directly.